# Updating the position of a node constantly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am experiencing some problems with my game, I am currently using the update method to create the illusion of my Hero character being "dragged" along with a moving platform. The update method works by using a bool that switches on and off whenever my Hero makes contact with the platform and then updates the position to seemingly show that the Hero is being moved. This worked nicely, but as I realize when the framerate drops, so does the character's positioning and it breaks the illusion.

Is there any sort of way to constantly update the positioning of a node without using the update method?

**didBeginContact Method**

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

if (((firstBody.categoryBitMask & fPlayerCategory) != 0) && ((secondBody.categoryBitMask & fPlatformCategory) != 0))
     {
         [_Hero removeActionForKey:@"idleAnimation"];
         [_Hero runAction:repeatWalkAnimation withKey:@"walkAnimation"];
         syncMove = YES;

     }
}
```

**Update Method**

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
if (gameStart == YES & gameOver == NO) {

if (syncMove == YES) {

    _Hero.position = CGPointMake(_Hero.position.x - .83, _Hero.position.y);
}

}
}
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is making the framerate drop? Isn't that the real question ? None of the code above is relevant to solving that problem. The question misses the mark of what you should be focusing on. When the framerate drops, things will move slower and choppier. That's not changing via something related to the code we see here.

Comment: @prototypical - well said.

Comment: @prototypical Thanks. I suppose I have to work around it.

Comment: Work around framerate drops as opposed to solve them ? Seems like a recipe for disappointment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `currentTime` argument in your `update` function to calculate how much `_Hero` should have moved. This way `_Hero` will always move the appropriate amount based on the time since the last update.

The steps to do this are:

1. Store your last update time
2. On each update, calculate the difference between the last update time and the current time
3. Calculate how far `_Hero` should have moved in that time
4. Update `_Hero`'s position

Something like:

```
CFTimeInterval lastUpdateTime = 0;
CGFloat frameRate = 1.0 / 60.0; // Normal SpriteKit frame rate
CGFloat xDistanceForNormalFrameRate = 0.83;

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if (lastUpdateTime == 0) lastUpdateTime = currentTime - frameRate; // Init lastUpdateTime to one frame back

    if (gameStart && !gameOver) { // Note: the original question had & here, but it looks like it was a typo
        if (syncMove) {
            CFTimeInterval timeDifference = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
            CGFloat xDistance = xDistanceForNormalFrameRate * (timeDifference / frameRate);
            _Hero.position = CGPointMake(_Hero.position.x - xDistance, _Hero.position.y);
        }
    }

    lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
}
```

**Note:** *If your frame rate is dropping below ~30FPS, you should probably focus more on why your frame rate is dropping than how to work around it.*